# Undefined reference error linking GLFW on MinGW

Tags: c++, glfw, mingw32

My problem is that when I try to compile the makefile file, it gives me an error although I think I have set everything correctly

[image]

This is my current file system, but when i try to compile he give me this error

```
../src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `glfwInit
../src/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
...
```

My `main.cpp` look like this

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
 
#include <iostream>
 
int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
 
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "this is NOT a window!", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
 
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
 
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
 
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        
        glfwPollEvents();
 
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
 
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

and the command in my makefile is `g++ -g --std=c++17 -I../include -L../lib ../src/*.cpp ../src/glad.c -lglfw3dll -o main`

Comment: Your command is correct for building with the static version of the glfw library, but your screen shot only shows the link library and DLL. Do you get any kind of library not found error messages?

Comment: You don’t just point to the libs directory. Point at the file

Comment: @john No, no error messages for libraries not found

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean?

Comment: @Klayser So are you trying to build with the static version? Where is it located?

Comment: @john in the include folder

Comment: @Klayser Your library is in the include folder? I'm not talking about the header file, I'm talknig about the library.

Comment: @Klayser glfw3.dll.a is the link library for glfw, but you are not using that. You are linking with the static library, but that is nowhere to be seen in your screen shot.

Comment: @Klayser Anyway my guess would be that you are trying to link with a library that you don't have. Just a guess, here's the [documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_win32).

Comment: @john To clarify, I followed a tutorial to do the setup, then when it gave me the error I tried some solutions found and one of them was to rename the file libglfw3dll.a in glfw.dll.a, once tried it kept on does not work. I downloaded the pre-compiled glfw and put the includes in my include folder and the glfw3.dll file in bin and libglfwdll.a in lib, I don't know if it's correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249537/discussion-between-klayser-and-john).

Comment: Perhaps you're using an x32 lib with an x64 compiler, or vice versa?

Comment: @Klayser The library you are trying to link with is called (I think) libgflw3.a. However it seems you have no such library. So I guess your binary download did not include the static version of the library. If that is the case then you should probably try to link with the link library instead of the static library, you do have that version of the library. Read the instructions in the documentation I posted, and try that.

Comment: @Klayser Another possibility is the one that HolyBlackCat mentions, you do have the right library but its the wrong version, a 32 bit vs 64 bit error.

Comment: @Klayser Never rename files or copy files around as some kind of quick hack, when you don't really know what you are doing, that is just asking for trouble. Read the official documentation carefully, and try to do what it says.

Comment: @Klayser I lost track, but if your current position is that you don't have an official glfw installation because you have renamed or copied files, then you really must delete everything and start again. There is no point at all in working with a corrupted installation of the library.

Comment: @Klayser I can't stress this enough, you make these things work by writing the correct code and using the correct compiler options. Copying or renaming files is almost never the right thing to do.